# Слияние двух упорядоченных массивов с минимальным количеством перестановок

Tags: алгоритм, массивы

Есть ли какие-нибудь готовые алгоритмы для следующей задачи?

Дано:
Два упорядоченных массива содержащих целые числа. Необходимо слить первый массив во второй при следующих ограничениях:

- Второй массив нельзя расширять, он имеет фиксированную длину. В нем могут находиться пустые ячейки в произвольных местах, соответственно количество элементов в первом массиве не больше чем пустых ячеек во втором.
- Сохранять упорядоченность второго массива необходимо на каждом шаге.
- Временно удалять текущие элементы во втором массиве нельзя.
- Необходимо сделать минимальное количество перестановок.

Если есть какие-нибудь идеи рад буду их выслушать.

Comment: @Abyx и какое прилагательное тогда к массиву использовать?

Comment: Нормальный вопрос (условия, конечно, несколько искусственные). Не думаю, что его стоит закрывать. Вполне допускаю, что кто-нибудь захочет размяться и решить такую задачку.

Comment: идея проста: во втором массиве для каждого элемента понять, в какую сторону его нужно двигать (вверх/вниз), и перемещать элементы, расходясь в обе стороны от позиций "смены направления", для которых ближайший сверху сосед должен быть подвинут вниз, а ближайший снизу - вверх.  Каждый элемент будет перемещён не более 1 раза.